# How can solve 'error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: Connection was reset, errno 10054' when pushing files to a github repository?

Tags: git, github, repository, github-pages

I initialized git and I did `git push -u origin master` but when I'm trying to push files to my github repository I get these logs in my terminal

```
Enumerating objects: 118, done.
Counting objects: 100% (118/118), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (118/118), done.
Writing objects: 100% (118/118), 2.78 MiB | 2.55 MiB/s, done.
Total 118 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: Connection was reset, errno 10054
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

And turns out it hasn't push anyhting to repository and my repo is still empty .
How can I solve this error and push to my repo ?

Comment: git config --global http.sslVerify "false" as described here https://debugah.com/error-rpc-failed%EF%BC%9B-curl-56-openssl-ssl_read-connection-was-reset-errno-10054-2143/ solved it for me

Comment: Please do not blindly set `http.sslVerify` to `false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the error by building my project again and git init and other steps again and finally it worked

Answer (score 3):

Some reasons you know(I am a developer from China), and I also encountered this problem, but I have not solved it after seeing many solutions.

Finally, I replaced a vpn and it took effect. I hope it will help you. This problem may be a network problem.

```sh
# this is error
$ git push origin master
Enumerating objects: 494, done.
Counting objects: 100% (494/494), done.
Delta compression using up to 6 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (467/467), done.
Writing objects: 100% (491/491), 23.12 MiB | 112.20 MiB/s, done.
Total 491 (delta 36), reused 1 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number, errno 0
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date

# this is ok
$ git push origin master
Enumerating objects: 494, done.
Counting objects: 100% (494/494), done.
Delta compression using up to 6 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (467/467), done.
Writing objects: 100% (491/491), 23.11 MiB | 110.05 MiB/s, done.
Total 491 (delta 37), reused 1 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (37/37), done.
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello I am Chetan(I am student from Pune) from India. According to me this error is coming because of internet connection issue or might your network slow/unstable. You can fix this error by reconnecting your network or upgrading your internet speed. Than push your code again.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Self introduction is not required in your answer, and the solution to upgrade internet speed needs supporting information.

Answer (score 0):

git config --global http.postBuffer 5242880000